# Angular - Detect name or id of the div which has scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

Im trying to do a small task of querying the DB and getting sets of records for each scroll inside a div element.
What i tried is using window.scroll function, since it handles the whole page scroll functionality, I'm unable to detect from which div the scroll happened.
You'll help highly needed.

Comment: _detect from which div the scroll happened_ i don't think this is possible

Comment: You can set the onscroll="whenScrollHappens()" for every div. You will be able to find out which div triggers the scroll

Comment: If you set "whenScrollHappens()" as an onscroll event - it will be very expensive in terms of performance - it would be better to have a variable that is updated on the focus of each div / section. The id of the focussed div could update this variable on each div gaining focus and would allow a more performant awareness of the div that is being scrolled. So on each div becoming focussed - its id is set as the "active" div and thus the origin of the scroll event. It does mean a global variable however.

Comment: thank you all for the answers provided. I will update this thread, when i do complete this. thank you. :)